# Need to access User Machine related information and how to identify user accessing chatbot application through the device is Mobile or Laptop

Tags: microsoft-teams, .net-core-3.1, botframework

I have created a bot framework application like chatbot in .net core 3.1 which is deployed on Azure and this chatbot application is using by a number of users of an IT company through MS Teams. So through MS Teams can we access User Machine related information like (windows username, computer name, device OS, device Machine Architecture(86/64)). Can we identify from which device (Mobile/Laptop) the user is interacting with our Chatbot application through Teams? actually, we want to perform some automation activity on the user machine based on user input and this automation would only execute on a laptop or desktop but not on the mobile devices, so need to identify if user is sending out the response from a mobile phone or a laptop. Please provide help on that.

Comment: You will receive the machine related info under Turncontect.activity.entities: platform.

Comment: thanks,  Nikitha-MSFT for the valuable answer, it is working for me to identify users' devices.

Answer (score 0):

**Re: Need to access User Machine related information and how to identify user accessing chatbot application through the device is Mobile or Laptop.**

Coping the answer for better visibility

You will receive the machine related info under Turncontect.activity.entities: platform.

Comment: thanks, Jagadeesh-MSFT for the valuable answer, it is working for me to identify users' devices.